# How to control UISearchDisplayController's own table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my application, when I am not filtering my table, when I tap on a cell, its frame height is increased in order to display a `UIProgressView` that shows download progress.

However, when I filter the fetched results controller data with a `UISearchDisplayController`, the cells in this filtered table view do not behave in the same way.

Instead, the cell does not resize, does not show the progress view, does not trigger a download, and the application subsequently crashes.

How do I gain control over the table view that is presented when filtering results with `UISearchDisplayController`?

**EDIT**

Here is my `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. It's a bit long, but the gist is that it works fine when I'm not searching.

I think I need to adapt this somehow, so that it can work with whatever table view / fetched results controller that the search results controller is throwing at this.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([self.searchBar isFirstResponder])
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    MyObject *_myObject = (MyObject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.isSimulatingFileHierarchy) 
    {   
        if ([_myObject isFolder]) 
        {
            ObjectsViewController *_objectsViewController = [[ObjectsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ObjectsViewController" bundle:nil];
            _objectsViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
            _objectsViewController.nodeID = self.nodeID;
            _objectsViewController.nodeName = self.nodeName;
            _objectsViewController.parentObjectKey = [_myObject cleanedKey];

            if (self.parentObjectKey)
                _objectsViewController.title = [[_myObject cleanedKey] stringByTrimmingPrefix:[self.parentObjectKey stringByAppendingString:@"/"]];
            else 
                _objectsViewController.title = [_myObject cleanedKey];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:_objectsViewController animated:YES];
            UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
            [_backButton release];
            [_objectsViewController release];
        }
        else {
            //
            // If we don't have data cached for this object, we add a request for the object's bytes to the objectRequestQueue
            // 
            // 1. We add a progress indicator to the object's cell (we have an indexPath)
            // 2. We store the data to the Documents folder
            //
            // Once we have the data, we push a ViewerViewController subclass that is specific to the object content type 
            //

            if ((!_myObject.isDownloading) && ([_myObject.localPath length] == 0)) 
            {
                if ([AwsObject objectContentSupportedForType:[_myObject.contentType intValue]]) 
                {
                    //
                    // Start request and redraw row with UIProgressView
                    //
                    [self triggerObjectRequestAdditionForObject:_myObject atIndexPath:indexPath];
                }
                else {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ObjectsViewObjectRequestUnsupportedTypeAlertViewTitle", @"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"ObjectsViewObjectRequestUnsupportedTypeAlertViewMessage", @"") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ObjectsViewObjectRequestUnsupportedTypeAlertViewContinue", @""), nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];
                }
            }
            else if ((_myObject.isDownloading) && ([_myObject.localPath length] == 0)) 
            {
                //
                // Cancel request and redraw row without progress view
                //
                [self triggerObjectRequestRemovalForObject:_myObject atIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            else if ((!_myObject.isDownloading) && ([_myObject.localPath length] != 0)) 
            {
                //
                // Launch viewer for supported MIME type
                //
                switch ([_myObject.contentType intValue]) {
                    case kObjectContentTypeApplicationMsword: {
                        [self pushWebViewerViewController:_myObject withTextEncoding:@"UTF-8"];
                        break;
                    }
                    // handle other MIME types here...
                }
            }
            else {
                if ([_myObject isFolder]) { }
                else {
                    if ((!_myObject.isDownloading) && ([_myObject.localPath length] == 0))
                        [self triggerObjectRequestAdditionForObject:_myObject atIndexPath:indexPath];
                    else if ((_myObject.isDownloading) && ([_myObject.localPath length] == 0))
                        [self triggerObjectRequestRemovalForObject:_myObject atIndexPath:indexPath];
                    else if ((!_myObject.isDownloading) && ([_myObject.localPath length] != 0)) {
                        switch ([_myObject.contentType intValue]) {
                            case kObjectContentTypeApplicationMsword: {
                                [self pushWebViewerViewController:_myObject withTextEncoding:@"UTF-8"];
                                break;
                            }
                            // handle other MIME types here...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In any of the table view delegate methods, you can detect if you are working with the UISearchDisplayController's table view by using the following check:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
  // behavior specific to search display controller table view
}
else {
  // behavior specific to the original, unfiltered table view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would check if the table view being passed to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is equal to your search display controller's "searchResultsTableView" and program alternate behavior for that case.

It sounds like your issue may be more complicated. Can you post the code for `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?